# Reusing generated CSS classes as mixins

Tags: css, less

I have generated a font weight function for my application which is using Less. The issue is that I can't declare it in my Less code. Whereas if I embedded in HTML, it's working fine.

Here is the code I am using:

**Less:**

```
@fontSelectors: 300, 400, 700, 900;
each(@fontSelectors, {
  .font-@{value} { font-weight: @value; }
});

.font-700; // Error 
h1 { .font-700; } // Error
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="font-700"></div> <!-- Working -->
```

What I am doing wrong? How to declare for some other class parameter too?

Can anybody guide me?

Thanks

Comment: *`h1 { .font-700; }`* - this is totally wrong approach. If you need some *mixin* to emit some (whatever) properties depending on some parameter - the parameter should be just that: *parameter* and not a part of the "mixin" name.

Comment: I.e. what you really need is just [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/af5efb59fa90b2984c405c859c9cde24)

Comment: Hi @seven-phases-max, thanks for your response. I agree with your comment. Its just that I wanted to make this mixin both for usage with HTML and LESS approaches with dynamically generated classes. Could there be any other alternative for same approach but with different idea??

Comment: *this mixin both for usage with HTML and LESS* and that's what is exactly wrong with it. Either way (and aside of above, as I don't want to bother you with all args for and against - you''ll find them elsewhere) - you can't use a CSS class with its name being a result of a concatenation (either via nesting or variable interpolation) as a mixin. This is just not supported.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. I consider your comment accurate for my question. Thanks..